# snippet fields within quotation marks

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to create a snippet, but when I try to move through the fields by hitting `tab`
for fields within `""` it autocompetes the `"` instead of jumping to the next field and breaks.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a broken "${2:snippet}", ${3:this} field won't be reached!
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>testsnip</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: It's working fine for me using ST3 Build 3054 on XP. What version and platform are you on?

Comment: it was on Windows XP. Works on Win 7 though. I'll have to check the build tomorrow!

Comment: Do you have a key binding set up to move past quotes, brackets, etc? If so, that's probably what's triggering, not an autocomplete. You can probably modify the context of that key to include something like `{ "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }` to get the behavior you want.

Comment: @skuroda brilliant! you should post this as an answer! I'll happily upvote and accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a key binding set up to move past quotes, brackets, etc? If so, that's probably what's triggering, not an autocomplete. You can probably modify the context of that key to include something like `{ "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }` to get the behavior you want.

As a debugging tip, enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the ST console. That way you can see what command is being run. This can help narrow down what a particular problem is.